# Add database fields according to id php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've been trying to output my database fields according to their `empid`, but I somehow can't. it gives me this error..

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:_webhost\Apache24\htdocs\eis\usercp.inc.php on line 16

```
<?php       
$firstname =  getuserfield('txtFname');
$lastname = getuserfield('txtLname');
echo 'Hello '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'.';
$empid = getuserfield('empid');
$query = "SELECT type_of_leave,specific_reason,date_from,date_to,num_of_days FROM `hrf_leave` WHERE `empid` = '$empid' AND `formStatus` = 0";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Type of Leave</th>
<th>Specific Reason</th>
<th>Date From</th>
<th>Date To</th>
<th>Number of Days</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){ // line 16
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $record['type_of_leave'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['specific_reason'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['date_from'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['date_to'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $record['num_of_days'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: put or `die(mysql_error())` after mysql_query;

Comment: I tried that. I found the problem, I forgot to save mysql table after doing some alteration. But it still doesn't output the results i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boolean `false` is passed from `mysql_query()` since your sql statement `$query` is invalid. Therefor `mysql_fetch_array()` returns the above error.

Try this as `$query`, it will solve if it is a syntax error I hope.

```
   $query= SELECT * FROM hrf_leave WHERE empid = '$empid' AND formStatus = 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

See there might be 2 things :-

1. First the **empid** you used in the query might be integer and you are passing the value with in quotes.
2. Second the query is not returning any result. echo out the query and run it in the phpmyadmin or any mysql query browser.

Suggestion : Before using mysql_fetch_array use mysql_num_rows to check that if any rows are returned from the query.

Note : mysql_* functions are being depreciated. So avoid them

Comment: i tried outputting 1 field in the database using $row =mysql_fetch_assoc(query_run) and echoing it like this $row['id'] but nothing popped out

Comment: @Carnal I know its late but do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything please try to not use mysql_  function  its no more supported 
You can use pdo. Bellow is how to connect to the datadabase using  pdo  from there you have to learn  how to query pdo  gud luck  .
    getMessage();
    }
    ?>